# Load external js in external html file in Webview [vscode-extensions]

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to create a webview in my extension with external HTML file and load an external js file in script tag.

The HTML file gets loaded properly but the HTML file is unable to open the js file. I tried to load from both ways - `Option A` and `Option B`. But none of them worked. I referred other similar questions on SO related to this but didn't had much help.

On checking the debugger console `Ctrl+Shift+P`, I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Here is the code snippet

**extension.ts**

```
let htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'), 'utf8')

export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    ...
    ...
    const onDiskPath = vscode.Uri.file(
        path.join(context.extensionPath, 'out', 'index.js')
    );

    // const jsFileSrc = panel.webview.asWebviewUri(onDiskPath);        //Option A
    const jsFileSrc = onDiskPath.with({ scheme: 'vscode-resource' });   //Option B
    console.log(jsFileSrc);
    panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent(jsFileSrc);
    ...
    ...
}

export function getWebviewContent(jsFileSrc:vscode.Uri){
    return `${htmlContent}`
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cat Coding</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="{{jsFileSrc}}"><script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it work when you put the contents of the javascript file in-line of the html?

Comment: @Yanichka Ariunbold Yes, It does. It also works when I put the contents of HTML file in the `extension.ts` file i.e. everything in `return `  of `getWebviewContent` and load the js file from there by doing `${jsFileSrc}` in `src`.

Answer (score 0):

fisrt you need define content security policy with meta tag. That works for me

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src self; img-src vscode-resource:; script-src vscode-resource: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src vscode-resource: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; "/>
```

And allow use script in webview config.

second you need path your HTML. I'm use xmldom.

```
const XML = require('xmldom');
const PATH = require('path');
//base_path = context.extensionPath
function pathHTML(html, base_path){ 

    const doc = new XML.DOMParser().parseFromString(
        html,
        'text/html' //It is important, html may be not valid XML document
    ); 
    for (let script of doc.getElementsByTagName('script')){
        let path = PATH.parse(script.getAttribute('src')); //use relative path

        path = `vscode-resource: ${PATH.resolve(base_path, path)}`;
        //The documentation says use vscode.Uri.file, but my varinat works too.
        script.setAttribute('src', path);
    }

    return new XML.XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);
}
```